# woocommerce booking and Woocommerce get_customer_note();

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I am trying to show get_customer_note(); in woocommerce booking plugin
Everything is working but It is not getting customer notes from orders.
My codee

```
<p class="form-field form-field-wide">
                                <label for="excerpt"><?php _e( 'Customer provided note', 'woocommerce-bookings' ); ?>:</label>
                                <textarea rows="1" cols="40" name="excerpt" tabindex="6" id="excerpt" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Customer notes about the order', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                                <?php 
                                $customer_note = $order->get_customer_note();
                                echo wp_kses_post( $customer_note->post_excerpt );
                                ?></textarea>
                            </p>
```

It is not getting customer notes from woocommerce.

Comment: @gaurav-sharma Can you help me update data, its not updating the customer notes from woocommerce-bookings plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Get all Customer notes by order id

```
//Call fun
$order_id = 703;
$_customer_note = cc_get_customer_notes($order_id);
echo "<pre>_customer_note: "; print_r($_customer_note); echo "</pre>";

/*
* Get Customer notes
*/
function cc_get_customer_notes($order_id){

  global $wpdb;

  $_customer_note_data = array();

  $q = "
  SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}comments 
  WHERE comment_post_ID = '{$order_id}' 
  AND comment_ID IN (
    SELECT comment_id FROM 
    {$wpdb->prefix}commentmeta 
    WHERE meta_key='is_customer_note' 
    AND meta_value=1
  ) 
  ";

  $_customer_note = $wpdb->get_results($q);
  if (count($_customer_note) > 0) {
   $_customer_note_data = $_customer_note;
  }

  return $_customer_note_data;

}
```

Comment: Still nothing, I want to show this https://prnt.sc/213g1ys in woocommerce booking https://prnt.sc/213g270 here. But it is not getting value from woo commerce plugin

Comment: Check my next post

Answer (score 0):

Get Shipping Customer notes

```
$order_id = 703;
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
//echo "<pre>order: "; print_r($order); echo "</pre>";
$customer_note = $order->get_customer_note();
echo "<pre>customer_note: "; print_r($customer_note); echo "</pre>";
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Still showing nothing https://prnt.sc/213gfpn, It is not getting the data

Comment: Ok I understand this is a booking plugin not woocommerce plugin, could you please share the plugin URL which you are using for booking

Comment: yes its plugin, I just want to show woocommerce customer notes in this plugin order details https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/

Comment: Bro Did you find any solution?

Comment: Woocommerce booking is paid plugin, I can't reproduce the issue in my environment if you provide GitHub repository then I can try.

Comment: https://github.com/hamzabutt1000/woocomerce-booking/blob/main/class-wc-bookings-details-meta-box.php
You can see that code on Line 237

Comment: First, check the record  in wp_post table available  or not in respect to order_id:
https://prnt.sc/213qg09

Comment: Run this query in the database
SELECT post_excerpt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='shop_order' AND ID = 703

And check if customer notes are available or not

Comment: Its working, Actually I just want to show customer notes in Woocommerce Booking plugin so that I dont have to go to woocomerce plugin to see customer notes. Or Is there any way to copy meta boxes of woocomerce to woocomerce-booking plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with this code:

```html
<p class="form-field form-field-wide">

    <label for="excerpt"><?php _e('Customer provided note', 'woocommerce-bookings'); ?>:</label>
    <textarea rows="1" cols="40" name="excerpt" tabindex="6" id="excerpt" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Customer notes about the order', 'woocommerce'); ?>">
        <?php
          $order = wc_get_order($booking->get_order_id());
          $customer_note = $order->get_customer_note();
          echo wp_kses_post($customer_note);
        ?>
    </textarea>
</p>
```

I just want to make it so that I can save/update customer notes from woocommerce-booking plugin. instead of going to woocommerce order page. Any ideas???